# Problems parsing XML with jQuery in Firefox

Tags: jquery, xml, firefox

I'm using JavaScript/jQuery trying to parse an XML document that's been fetched via an AJAX Get request. I can't post the XML document, but it is well-formed and the tags that I'm looking for are present. The AJAX request is successful and returns the full XML document in both Chrome and Firefox--now I just can't parse it, for some reason. The code is working in Chrome but not Firefox or IE. I'm not really interested in IE right now, but I'm lost as to why it isn't working in Firefox.

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function getGroupSets() {
$.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "application/xml",
    url: '../api/indicatorGroupSets.xml',
    success: function( xml ) {

        /*Find Indicator Group Set tags in XML file */

        alert($(xml).find('indicatorGroupSet').length);
        //This alert reads '0' in Firefox, '4' in Chrome
        //The following function is not executed in Firefox:

        $( xml ).find( 'indicatorGroupSet' ).each( function( ) {

            /*For each Set, get the name & ID*/

            var groupSet = {
                name: $( this ).attr( 'name' ),
                id: $( this ).attr( 'id' )
            };
            alert(groupSet.name);
            //Nothing displays here
        } );
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

        /*If an error occurs, alert the issue and a message to users */

        alert( jqXHR + ':' + textStatus + ':' + errorThrown + '\nThere has been an error, please refresh the page or contact the site administrator if the problem persists.' );
    }
} );
}
```

I've been looking for solutions for most of the day, but everything seems to be about how a parser isn't working in IE, not much on this issue in Firefox.

I appreciate any input!

Comment: In some examples I had quite some problems with jQuery not being able to handle namespaces within XML documents. I just switched to using native JavaScript, which worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try telling jQuery that you are loading HTML instead. It is my experience that jQuery can't traverse XML in Firefox. It is possible that some unknown, specific conditions trigger this behaviour.

```
$.get("example.xml", function(data) {
    ....
}, "html");
```

It is necessary to traverse the document using the localName property, if your document contains namespaces:

```
if (this.localName === "c:tagname") {
    ....
}
```

It is possible to navigate the document using normal jQuery functionality, if it doesn't contain namespaces:

```
if ($(this).is("tagname")) {
    ....
}
```

Far from pretty, but gets the job done. In Firefox, at least. :)

Comment: localname property? i am having same problem in FF,xml reading working in chrome but not in FF